# Mix an array on Laravel Collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, iteration, laravel-collection

I have an array looks like this code bellow:

```
$arr = ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

And I use Laravel Collection for this array, so the code looks like this:

```
$collect = collect($arr);
```

I was tried using this following code but still give the same array:

```
$return_arr = [];
    $return_arr = $collect->each(function($item) {
                if(!empty($return_arr)) {
                    if(gettype($item) == gettype($newArr[count($newArr) - 1]) ) 
                    {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return $item;
                    }
                } else {
                    return $item;
                }
            });
```

And also, I was tried using manual foreach loop like this following code, but it not return all element:

```
$return_arr = [];

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if(!empty($return_arr)) {
        if(gettype($return_arr[count($return_arr) - 1]) == gettype($item)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $return_arr[] = array_push($return_arr, $item);
        }
    } else {
        $return_arr[]= array_push($return_arr, $item);
    }
}
print_r($return_arr);
// return Array ( [0] => a [1] => 1 [2] => b [3] => 3 [4] => c [5] => 5 )
```

What I want is return new collection with array value looks like this:

```
$return_arr = ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Can you guys give me help

Thanks in advance

Comment: look like simple looping and array manipulation but you need to show us what you tried and where you are stuck, this is not a place to ask people to write code for you.

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Sorry, I forgot to tell you what I was tried.. Thanks Shubham

Comment: Why did you not using simple for loop instead of using laravel collection

Comment: @SachinKumar I was tried but not return all element of an array, thanks Sachin

Comment: so you want to mix string and integer?

Comment: @Alzafan Cristian yes.. right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to interleave items based on their type you can try :

```
$collection = collect($array)->groupBy(function ($value) {
    return gettype($value);
});

$interleaved = $collection->first()->zip($collection->last())->flatten()->filter();
```

This will:

1. Group items by type
2. Take the first group and zip it with the last group (this assumes you have exactly 2 groups)
3. It will then flatten the result and filter out null values

Note: You might need to add a check to determine if the string group is first or last and adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to shuffle the collections contents to a random set try the `shuffle()` method like this:

```
$arr = ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
$collection = collect($arr);

$shuffled = $collection->shuffle();

$mixed_array = $shuffled->all();
```

This will give you this output:

```
=> ["b",4,5"c",2,3,"a",1,6,]
```

Answer (score 0):

its dirty, but you can try:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2];
//split strings and integers
$string = Arr::where($array, function ($value, $key) {
  return is_string($value);
});

$integer = Arr::where($array, function ($value, $key) {
  return is_int($value);
});

$integer = array_values($integer);
$combine = [];
foreach (array_values($string) as $key => $value) {
    $combine[] = $value;
    if(array_key_exists($key, $integer)){
        $combine[] = $integer[$key];
        unset($integer[$key]);
    }
}
$combine = array_merge($combine, $integer);
//["a", 1, "b", 2, "c"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much  @Alzafan Christian . I was tried your code .. and its work.

Comment: @bagongpct you can use apokryfos code, as its more clean using Collection than mine

Comment: Sure, Thanks @Alzafan Cristian